# Bad request error when calling a custom action through Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I created a custom action on CRM 365 which has one input parameter of type entity reference and it refers to the user entity, I tried to change the input parameter into another type and it works well. So I think the issue is in the way I pass the entity reference value, I tried to change it but I haven't had any luck so can someone tell me what is the wrong in the below code?

```js
function CreateBlockHistory() {
    var Id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    Id = Id.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
    var data = {
        "BlockedBy": {
            "ohd_blockedby": Xrm.Page.context.getUserId().replace("}", "").replace("{", ""),
            "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser"
        }
    };
    var serverURL = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", serverURL + "/api/data/v8.1/new_units(" + Id + ")/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ohd_ActionTest", false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 /* request completed */) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status == 200 /* response ready */) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
            }
            else {
                var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(window.JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: I see you are using both Xrm & window.parent.Xrm - can you verify that expected values are coming there? Also try singular entity name new_unit

Comment: Have you tried using `Xrm.WebApi`?

Comment: i make sure form the values and they are correct as they should, the entity name is correct because when i tried to change the parameter type it works well ,

Comment: I recommend you to use CRM REST Builder to build query, execute & test.

Comment: https://futurezconsulting.com/2018/06/25/crm-mini-web-server/

Comment: You should be able to see the request being posted in the Network tab (or use Fiddler) to see the request and response. Have you confirmed that `Xrm.Page.context.getUserId()` is returning a value?

Comment: @YasminShams any luck?

Answer (score 0):

1. To start with `400 Bad request` - it is a very generic useless error, instead of relying on this - try to run the same snippet in browser console or CRM REST Builder by passing hardcoded guid parameters to see execution status. You can debug too
2. I see your `XMLHttpRequest` is running synchronous ( bool param as false), switch it to Async & see
3. Also I see you are getting `Xrm` context with mixed approach like `window.parent` sometimes & directly sometimes. `window.JSON` too. If this is executing in web resource not in any entity form then fix it appropriately
4. You can register a plugin on that custom action message, profile/debug & see for any clue